# Clear cache when writing stream to browser

Tags: java, struts2

I am using Struts 2 and I wrote the following code to download Zip from client side. It works locally fine but when remote user(Different network) tries to download , they are getting error that page not found.

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
    ZipEntry ze= new ZipEntry("test.xml");
    zos.putNextEntry(ze);
    for(MessagesList messageEntry:allMessages){
        String headers= "<Message>\n<Header>\n";
        Map<String,String> header = messageEntry.getTradeMessages().getJmsHeaders();
        String keyValue="";
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : header.entrySet()){
             keyValue += entry.getKey()+":"+entry.getValue()+",";
        }
        headers += keyValue+"\n</Header>\n";
        zos.write(headers.getBytes());
        String contents="<Body>\n"+messageEntry.getTradeMessages().getMessageContent()+"</Body>\n</Message>\n";
        zos.write(contents.getBytes());
    }
    zos.closeEntry(); 
    zos.close();

    stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());


    return "download";
```

Comment: We need MORE information. A stacktrace, your environment, the relevant parts of your configurations (struts.xml, web.xml) AND the JSP or the URL you are using to call this action.

Comment: Does a remote user come via proxy?

Comment: no proxy. they are in different country and connecting via VPN

Comment: Here are also part of results annotation  @Result(name = "download", type = "stream", params = {"contentType", "application/zip", "inputName", "stream", "bufferSize", "1024", "contentDisposition", "attachment;filename=\"allMessages.zip\""}),

Answer (score 0):

here is code I tested and it worked fine .

```
    HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control",  "no-store, no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Pragma","");
```